# Output of c++ program not coming as expected

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have made a C++ program for a binary tree. But the terminal is not asking the statement for inputting the direction for where the elements are to be placed.
Also when I replace the statement from " node *temp = new node " to "node *temp=NULL" the program stops working .

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
class node {
    int data;
    node * left;
    node * right;
public:
    node * level_order(node * first);
    node * create_bt(node * first);
    void display(node * first);
};
//node *first=NULL;

node * node::create_bt(node * first) {
    node * temp = new node;
    int ele;
    //char dir;
    cout << "\n Enter data ";
    cin >> ele;
    temp->data = ele;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;

    if (first == NULL) {
        temp = first;
        return first;
    } else {
        char dir[20];
        cout << "\n Enter the direction ";
        cin >> dir;
        node * cur = first;
        int j = 0;
        while (dir[j] != '\0') {
            if (dir[j] == 'l') {
                cur = cur->left;
            }
            if (dir[j] == 'r') {
                cur = cur->right;
            }
            j++;
        }
        cur = temp;
        return first;
    }    
}

void node::display(node * first) {
    if (first == NULL)
        return;
    cout << "\n " << first->data;
    display(first->left);
    display(first->right);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    node s;
    node * first = NULL;
    cout << "\n No of elements ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        first = s.create_bt(first);
    }
    s.display(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to format your code properly before you ask questions. If the previous format was actually the one you use in your own code, then good luck trying to maintain your own code in your later job.

Answer (score 0):

first=s.create_bt(first); does not changes state, from NULL to 'l' or 'r'. You have to change that.

```
node*node::create_bt(node *first)
{
    node *temp=new node;
    int ele;
    //char dir;
    cout<<"\n Enter data ";
    cin>>ele;
    temp->data=ele;
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->right=NULL;
    char dir[20];
    cout<<"\n Enter the direction ";
    cin>>dir;
    if(first==NULL)
    {
        temp=first;
        return first;
    }
    else
    {
        node*cur=first;
        int j=0;
        while(dir[j]!='\0')
        {
            if(dir[j]=='l')
            {
                cur=cur->left;
            }
            if(dir[j]=='r')
            {
                cur=cur->right;
            }
            j++;
        }
        cur=temp;
        return first;
    }

}
```

Comment: But as it is returning the pointer to the first node. Why it isnt possible?

Comment: because when it comes to the if statement to check the "first==NULL" , it is true, due to the "node * first = NULL;" that you have declared in main(). It executes :

Comment: the if statement and returns the first value.

Comment: can u please explain in  a simple way. having trouble understanding

Answer (score 0):

I believe you re looking something like this. This is a basic binary tree, i had to make a basic one in order to understand how it works and how it chooses left and right. I make a class inside a class, in order to have access to my data members (node class, int data, *left , *right) and have them at the same time protected, all-in-one. As you can see "newnode" just creates a node and NULL s the pointers. Thats it. "Find" searches and finds a node with a current key, and returns it when exits. All the rest, i guess, you can understand them, as they are prety much the same with your code. The only thing you have to do is to define, when you want to direct the node you want. REMINDER: You have to find a way to utilize it, so the leafs will not end far-left or far-right.("Enter the direction"). I hope i helped you understand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
class mybTree {
class node {
public:
    int data;
    node * left;
    node *right;
};
node *root;
node *newnode(int num){
    node *newnode1;
    newnode1 = new (nothrow) node;
    newnode1->data = num;
    newnode1->left = NULL;
    newnode1->right = NULL;
    return newnode1;
}

public:
node *find (int key) {
    node *current;
    current = root;
    while  (current->data !=key){
        if (key<current->data){
            current = current->left;
        } else {
            current = current->right;

        }
        if (current == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void display (node *ptr);
void display_tree();
bool insert(int num);

void post_order_delete(node *ptr);
mybTree();
~mybTree();
};
int main(){
char ch = ' ';
int a;
mybTree mybTree1;
while (ch !='0'){
    cout << "0->Exit"<<endl<< "1-> add"<<endl<< "2-> find" <<endl<<"3-> Show me the tree\n";
    ch = getch();
    switch (ch) {
        case '0':
            break;
        case '1':
            cout << "number";
            cin >> a;
            if (!mybTree1.insert(a)){
                cout << "Not enough memory" << endl;
            }
            break;
        case '2' :
            cout << "Number:" ;
            cin >> a;
            if (mybTree1.find(a)!=NULL) {
                cout << "Found" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Not existed" << endl;
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            mybTree1.display_tree();
            cout<<endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong Message";
            break;
    }
}
return 0;
}

void mybTree::display(node *ptr) {
if (ptr == NULL){
    return;
}
display(ptr->left);
cout << ptr->data<<endl;
display(ptr->right);
}

void mybTree::display_tree() {
//Displays the Tree
display(root);
}

bool mybTree::insert(int num) {
//It inserts a node. Desides left or right.
node *next,*current,*ptr;
int isleft;
next = current = root;
ptr = newnode(num);
if (ptr == NULL) {
    return false;
}
if (root == NULL) {
    root = ptr;
    return  true;
}
while (1){
    if (num < current->data){
        next = current->left;
        isleft = 1;
    } else {
        next = current->right;
        isleft = 0;
    }
    if (next == NULL){
        if (isleft){
            current->left = ptr;
        } else {
            current->right = ptr;
        }
        return true;
    }
    current=next;
}
return false;
}

void mybTree::post_order_delete(node *ptr) {
//deletes the node. Usefull for destructor
if (ptr == NULL){
    return;
}
post_order_delete(ptr->left);
post_order_delete(ptr->right);
cout << ptr->data;
delete ptr;
}

mybTree::mybTree() {
//Constructor
root = NULL;
}

mybTree::~mybTree() {
//Destructor
post_order_delete(root);
root = NULL;
}
```